# the socket disconnect when running client\server python

Tags: python, sockets, visual-studio-code, tcp, txt

I am having a client-server program to send from the server to the client

the server in a different folder from the client (like there is a folder for the server code and another folder for the client code)

-when running the server and the client the server gives me an error that the socket disconnect and i don't know why:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server.py", line 30, in 
s.send(ans.encode(FORMAT))
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was s
upplied

## the server code:

```
import socket
import os
import json

SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"

# creating a TCP socket
print('\n','_'*50,"\n\nThe server started.. ")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5100))

# converted into passive socket - queue up to 2 requests
print("\n\nThe server is listening.. ")
s.listen(5)


while True:
    cli, sockname = s.accept()
    print('Accepted request from', sockname[0], 'with port number', sockname[1])

    listoffile= [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".txt")]
    ans =json.dumps(listoffile)
    thelist=ans.replace(',','\n').replace('[',"").replace('"',"").replace(']',"")+"\n exit"

    print('\n The server will send the list to the client:\n',thelist)
    s.sendall(ans.encode(FORMAT))
    rec = cli.recv(SIZE).encode(FORMAT)
    if rec != 'exit':
        with open(rec,'rb') as f:
            filetosend =f.read(SIZE)
            s.sendall(filetosend.encode(FORMAT))
    elif rec == 'exit':
        cli.close()
        s.close()
```

## The client code:

```
import socket
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5100
SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"

# creating a TCP socket
print('\n','_'*50,"\n\nThe client side started.. ")

c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect((host, port))

while True:
        
    msg = c.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
    msg=msg.replace(',','\n').replace('[',"").replace('"',"").replace(']',"")+"\n exit"
    print(f"Choose one of the file to get a copy: {msg}")
    filename = input("Enter the file name or exit to quit:")
    if filename != 'exit':
        c.send(filename.encode(FORMAT))
        f=open(filename,'wb')
        data=c.recv(SIZE)
        f.write(data)
        print('The file {filename} is copied.')
    elif filename == 'exit':
        c.close()
```

Comment: VS code could not open a two-terminal at file->newwindow<br>
you alse can use the comand(shell) in system, if you want debug, using pycharm

Comment: if you can tell how to open a two-terminal in pycharm as I am not familiar with it

Comment: You could just open two cmd windows, rather than using an embedded terminal, and just run them both there